# Zoom Bar Chart with mouse wheel

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I found many examples how to zoom in charts but I'm looking for basic example in which the user can scroll with the mouse wheel.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSample extends Application {
    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";
    final static String italy = "Italy";
    final static String usa = "USA";

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
            new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));      

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 41941.19));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));  

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 18722.18));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));  

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome.

P.S I tested to insert the code into ScrollPane but I don't see any effect of using it.

```
ScrollPane s1 = new ScrollPane();
        //s1.setPrefSize(620, 620);
        s1.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        s1.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        s1.setContent(bc);
```

Comment: The answer by *Lukas* works ! Are you looking for something else ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling) answer.

I've got it working with this code:

```
final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
bc.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
        event.consume();

        if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        double scaleFactor = (event.getDeltaY() > 0) ? SCALE_DELTA : 1 / SCALE_DELTA;

        bc.setScaleX(bc.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
        bc.setScaleY(bc.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
    }
});

bc.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            bc.setScaleX(1.0);
            bc.setScaleY(1.0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's working well. One more question how I can reset the original size? Maybe I can do this with double click?

Comment: I tested to add ScrollPane in order to fit the chart into boundaries and not to override nearby components but I don't see any effect. How I can use it with ScrollPane.

Comment: Eh, sorry but it's just a scale, not a zoom.

Comment: @MutenRoshi exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Jason Winnebeck's [JFXUtils](http://gillius.org/cgi-bin/mt/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=2&tag=JavaFX&limit=20). He has developed a really nice library for chart zooming as well as panning (dragging the zoomed chart area like Google Maps).

- You can also easily reset the chart. I wired it up to double click like you suggested.
- You can specify the format of the axis labels on his custom StableTicksAxis (I display dates and times on my x axis).
- Zooming works from a click-and-drag on the chart area or on the axis for zooming in to the entire span of either the x or y axis.
- Mouse wheel zooming is baked right in.
- He has a convenience method for super simple default setup, which wraps the chart in the components required to implement zooming.

Comment: Sorry for interfere but I dont think with JFXUtils you can work with Bar Chart. Bar Chart expects Category Axis, and JFXUtils doesnt work with them...