# Graph Visualisation (like yFiles) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graphviz

Something like Graphviz but more specifically, yFiles.

I want a node/edge type of graph visualization.

I was thinking about making the node a `Circle` and the edge a `Line`. The problem is what to use for the area where the nodes/edges appear. Should I use a `ScrollPane`, a regular `Pane`, a `Canvas`, etc...

I will add scrolling functionality, zooming, selecting nodes & dragging nodes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have something you want, but what is your question?  You should use a ScrollPane, but that is only one very small decision in what is a very complex task, so that is not an answer to the general question title, which would be far too broad for a StackOverflow question.  Incidentally, [yFiles for JavaFX](https://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesjavafx_about.html) is available from yWorks, though, in general, library recommendations are out of scope for StackOverflow, it is such a restrictive set of rules StackOverflow has ;-)

Comment: @jewelsea the question is how would I go about selecting the components for the project.

Comment: Well you could add Circles and Lines to a Group in a ScrollPane and create a basic graph viewer.  It wouldn't be yFiles by any stretch of the imagination, it would allow you to view a node graph.  But you probably want some information (like text) in the nodes, so instead of a Circle use a Label.  Zooming is tricky, so you probably want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling.  Getting the geometry right for the layout is also tricky, you probably want to use some library to assist with that. Not sure if this is a comment or an actual answer to your question.

Comment: @jewelsea Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I have to ask though - why put them in a `Group`?

Comment: Read the [ScrollPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html): "ScrollPane layout calculations are based on the layoutBounds rather than the boundsInParent (visual bounds) of the scroll node. If an application wants the scrolling to be based on the visual bounds of the node (for scaled content etc.), they need to wrap the scroll node in a Group."  You want to scroll scaled content based upon visual bounds, so you need a Group...

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I had 2 hours to kill, so I thought I'd give it a shot. Turns out that it's easy to come up with a prototype.

Here's what you need:

- a main class to use the graph library you create
- a graph with a data model
- easy adding and removing of nodes and edges (turns out that it's better to name the nodes cells in order to avoid confusion with JavaFX nodes during programming)
- a [zoomable scrollpane](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/zooming-inside-a-scrollpane/)
- a layout algorithm for the graph

It's really too much to be asked on SO, so I'll just add the code with a few comments.

The application instantiates the graph, adds cells and connects them via edges.

application/Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.fxgraph.graph.CellType;
import com.fxgraph.graph.Graph;
import com.fxgraph.graph.Model;
import com.fxgraph.layout.base.Layout;
import com.fxgraph.layout.random.RandomLayout;

public class Main extends Application {

    Graph graph = new Graph();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        graph = new Graph();

        root.setCenter(graph.getScrollPane());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        addGraphComponents();

        Layout layout = new RandomLayout(graph);
        layout.execute();

    }

    private void addGraphComponents() {

        Model model = graph.getModel();

        graph.beginUpdate();

        model.addCell("Cell A", CellType.RECTANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell B", CellType.RECTANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell C", CellType.RECTANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell D", CellType.TRIANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell E", CellType.TRIANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell F", CellType.RECTANGLE);
        model.addCell("Cell G", CellType.RECTANGLE);

        model.addEdge("Cell A", "Cell B");
        model.addEdge("Cell A", "Cell C");
        model.addEdge("Cell B", "Cell C");
        model.addEdge("Cell C", "Cell D");
        model.addEdge("Cell B", "Cell E");
        model.addEdge("Cell D", "Cell F");
        model.addEdge("Cell D", "Cell G");

        graph.endUpdate();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The scrollpane should have a white background.

application/application.css

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport {
   -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

The zoomable scrollpane, I got the [code base from pixel duke](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/zooming-inside-a-scrollpane/):

ZoomableScrollPane.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;

public class ZoomableScrollPane extends ScrollPane {
    Group zoomGroup;
    Scale scaleTransform;
    Node content;
    double scaleValue = 1.0;
    double delta = 0.1;

    public ZoomableScrollPane(Node content) {
        this.content = content;
        Group contentGroup = new Group();
        zoomGroup = new Group();
        contentGroup.getChildren().add(zoomGroup);
        zoomGroup.getChildren().add(content);
        setContent(contentGroup);
        scaleTransform = new Scale(scaleValue, scaleValue, 0, 0);
        zoomGroup.getTransforms().add(scaleTransform);

        zoomGroup.setOnScroll(new ZoomHandler());
    }

    public double getScaleValue() {
        return scaleValue;
    }

    public void zoomToActual() {
        zoomTo(1.0);
    }

    public void zoomTo(double scaleValue) {

        this.scaleValue = scaleValue;

        scaleTransform.setX(scaleValue);
        scaleTransform.setY(scaleValue);

    }

    public void zoomActual() {

        scaleValue = 1;
        zoomTo(scaleValue);

    }

    public void zoomOut() {
        scaleValue -= delta;

        if (Double.compare(scaleValue, 0.1) < 0) {
            scaleValue = 0.1;
        }

        zoomTo(scaleValue);
    }

    public void zoomIn() {

        scaleValue += delta;

        if (Double.compare(scaleValue, 10) > 0) {
            scaleValue = 10;
        }

        zoomTo(scaleValue);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param minimizeOnly
     *            If the content fits already into the viewport, then we don't
     *            zoom if this parameter is true.
     */
    public void zoomToFit(boolean minimizeOnly) {

        double scaleX = getViewportBounds().getWidth() / getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double scaleY = getViewportBounds().getHeight() / getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        // consider current scale (in content calculation)
        scaleX *= scaleValue;
        scaleY *= scaleValue;

        // distorted zoom: we don't want it => we search the minimum scale
        // factor and apply it
        double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        // check precondition
        if (minimizeOnly) {

            // check if zoom factor would be an enlargement and if so, just set
            // it to 1
            if (Double.compare(scale, 1) > 0) {
                scale = 1;
            }
        }

        // apply zoom
        zoomTo(scale);

    }

    private class ZoomHandler implements EventHandler<ScrollEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
            // if (scrollEvent.isControlDown())
            {

                if (scrollEvent.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scaleValue -= delta;
                } else {
                    scaleValue += delta;
                }

                zoomTo(scaleValue);

                scrollEvent.consume();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every cell is represented as Pane into which you can put any Node as view (rectangle, label, imageview, etc)

Cell.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Cell extends Pane {

    String cellId;

    List<Cell> children = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Cell> parents = new ArrayList<>();

    Node view;

    public Cell(String cellId) {
        this.cellId = cellId;
    }

    public void addCellChild(Cell cell) {
        children.add(cell);
    }

    public List<Cell> getCellChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void addCellParent(Cell cell) {
        parents.add(cell);
    }

    public List<Cell> getCellParents() {
        return parents;
    }

    public void removeCellChild(Cell cell) {
        children.remove(cell);
    }

    public void setView(Node view) {

        this.view = view;
        getChildren().add(view);

    }

    public Node getView() {
        return this.view;
    }

    public String getCellId() {
        return cellId;
    }
}
```

The cells should be created via some kind of factory, so they are classified by type:

CellType.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

public enum CellType {

    RECTANGLE,
    TRIANGLE
    ;

}
```

Instantiating them is quite easy:

RectangleCell.java

```
package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class RectangleCell extends Cell {

    public RectangleCell( String id) {
        super( id);

        Rectangle view = new Rectangle( 50,50);

        view.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        view.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);

        setView( view);

    }

}
```

TriangleCell.java

```
package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class TriangleCell extends Cell {

    public TriangleCell( String id) {
        super( id);

        double width = 50;
        double height = 50;

        Polygon view = new Polygon( width / 2, 0, width, height, 0, height);

        view.setStroke(Color.RED);
        view.setFill(Color.RED);

        setView( view);

    }

}
```

Then of course you need the edges. You can use any connection you like, even cubic curves. For sake of simplicity I use a line:

Edge.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class Edge extends Group {

    protected Cell source;
    protected Cell target;

    Line line;

    public Edge(Cell source, Cell target) {

        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;

        source.addCellChild(target);
        target.addCellParent(source);

        line = new Line();

        line.startXProperty().bind( source.layoutXProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
        line.startYProperty().bind( source.layoutYProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

        line.endXProperty().bind( target.layoutXProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
        line.endYProperty().bind( target.layoutYProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

        getChildren().add( line);

    }

    public Cell getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Cell getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

}
```

An extension to this would be to bind the edge to ports (north/south/east/west) of the cells.

Then you'd want to drag the nodes, so you'd have to add some mouse gestures. The important part is to consider a zoom factor in case the graph canvas is zoomed

MouseGestures.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class MouseGestures {

    final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

    Graph graph;

    public MouseGestures( Graph graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    public void makeDraggable( final Node node) {


        node.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
        node.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        node.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            double scale = graph.getScale();

            dragContext.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() * scale - event.getScreenX();
            dragContext.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()  * scale - event.getScreenY();

        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            double offsetX = event.getScreenX() + dragContext.x;
            double offsetY = event.getScreenY() + dragContext.y;

            // adjust the offset in case we are zoomed
            double scale = graph.getScale();

            offsetX /= scale;
            offsetY /= scale;

            node.relocate(offsetX, offsetY);

        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        }
    };

    class DragContext {

        double x;
        double y;

    }
}
```

Then you need a model in which you store the cells and the edges. Any time new cells can be added and existing ones can be deleted. You need to process them distinguished from the existing ones (e. g. to add mouse gestures, animate them when you add them, etc). When you implement the layout algorithm you'll be faced with the determination of a root node. So you should make an invisible root node (graphParent) which won't be added to the graph itself, but at which all nodes start that don't have a parent.

Model.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fxgraph.cells.TriangleCell;
import com.fxgraph.cells.RectangleCell;

public class Model {

    Cell graphParent;

    List<Cell> allCells;
    List<Cell> addedCells;
    List<Cell> removedCells;

    List<Edge> allEdges;
    List<Edge> addedEdges;
    List<Edge> removedEdges;

    Map<String,Cell> cellMap; // <id,cell>

    public Model() {

         graphParent = new Cell( "_ROOT_");

         // clear model, create lists
         clear();
    }

    public void clear() {

        allCells = new ArrayList<>();
        addedCells = new ArrayList<>();
        removedCells = new ArrayList<>();

        allEdges = new ArrayList<>();
        addedEdges = new ArrayList<>();
        removedEdges = new ArrayList<>();

        cellMap = new HashMap<>(); // <id,cell>

    }

    public void clearAddedLists() {
        addedCells.clear();
        addedEdges.clear();
    }

    public List<Cell> getAddedCells() {
        return addedCells;
    }

    public List<Cell> getRemovedCells() {
        return removedCells;
    }

    public List<Cell> getAllCells() {
        return allCells;
    }

    public List<Edge> getAddedEdges() {
        return addedEdges;
    }

    public List<Edge> getRemovedEdges() {
        return removedEdges;
    }

    public List<Edge> getAllEdges() {
        return allEdges;
    }

    public void addCell(String id, CellType type) {

        switch (type) {

        case RECTANGLE:
            RectangleCell rectangleCell = new RectangleCell(id);
            addCell(rectangleCell);
            break;

        case TRIANGLE:
            TriangleCell circleCell = new TriangleCell(id);
            addCell(circleCell);
            break;

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported type: " + type);
        }
    }

    private void addCell( Cell cell) {

        addedCells.add(cell);

        cellMap.put( cell.getCellId(), cell);

    }

    public void addEdge( String sourceId, String targetId) {

        Cell sourceCell = cellMap.get( sourceId);
        Cell targetCell = cellMap.get( targetId);

        Edge edge = new Edge( sourceCell, targetCell);

        addedEdges.add( edge);

    }

    /**
     * Attach all cells which don't have a parent to graphParent 
     * @param cellList
     */
    public void attachOrphansToGraphParent( List<Cell> cellList) {

        for( Cell cell: cellList) {
            if( cell.getCellParents().size() == 0) {
                graphParent.addCellChild( cell);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Remove the graphParent reference if it is set
     * @param cellList
     */
    public void disconnectFromGraphParent( List<Cell> cellList) {

        for( Cell cell: cellList) {
            graphParent.removeCellChild( cell);
        }
    }

    public void merge() {

        // cells
        allCells.addAll( addedCells);
        allCells.removeAll( removedCells);

        addedCells.clear();
        removedCells.clear();

        // edges
        allEdges.addAll( addedEdges);
        allEdges.removeAll( removedEdges);

        addedEdges.clear();
        removedEdges.clear();

    }
}
```

And then there's the graph itself which contains the zoomable scrollpane, the model, etc. In the graph the added and removed nodes are handled (mouse gestures, cells and edges added to the scrollpane, etc).

Graph.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Graph {

    private Model model;

    private Group canvas;

    private ZoomableScrollPane scrollPane;

    MouseGestures mouseGestures;

    /**
     * the pane wrapper is necessary or else the scrollpane would always align
     * the top-most and left-most child to the top and left eg when you drag the
     * top child down, the entire scrollpane would move down
     */
    CellLayer cellLayer;

    public Graph() {

        this.model = new Model();

        canvas = new Group();
        cellLayer = new CellLayer();

        canvas.getChildren().add(cellLayer);

        mouseGestures = new MouseGestures(this);

        scrollPane = new ZoomableScrollPane(canvas);

        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);

    }

    public ScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        return this.scrollPane;
    }

    public Pane getCellLayer() {
        return this.cellLayer;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void beginUpdate() {
    }

    public void endUpdate() {

        // add components to graph pane
        getCellLayer().getChildren().addAll(model.getAddedEdges());
        getCellLayer().getChildren().addAll(model.getAddedCells());

        // remove components from graph pane
        getCellLayer().getChildren().removeAll(model.getRemovedCells());
        getCellLayer().getChildren().removeAll(model.getRemovedEdges());

        // enable dragging of cells
        for (Cell cell : model.getAddedCells()) {
            mouseGestures.makeDraggable(cell);
        }

        // every cell must have a parent, if it doesn't, then the graphParent is
        // the parent
        getModel().attachOrphansToGraphParent(model.getAddedCells());

        // remove reference to graphParent
        getModel().disconnectFromGraphParent(model.getRemovedCells());

        // merge added & removed cells with all cells
        getModel().merge();

    }

    public double getScale() {
        return this.scrollPane.getScaleValue();
    }
}
```

A wrapper for the cell layer. You'll probably want to add multiple layers (e. g. a selection layer which highlights selected cells)

CellLayer.java

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class CellLayer extends Pane {

}
```

Now you need a layout for the cells. I suggest to create a simple abstract class which will get extended as you develop the graph.

```
package com.fxgraph.layout.base;

public abstract class Layout {

    public abstract void execute();

}
```

For sake of simplicity here's a simple layout algorithm in which random coordinates are used. Of course you'd have to do more complex stuff like tree layouts, etc.

RandomLayout.java

```
package com.fxgraph.layout.random;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;
import com.fxgraph.graph.Graph;
import com.fxgraph.layout.base.Layout;

public class RandomLayout extends Layout {

    Graph graph;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    public RandomLayout(Graph graph) {

        this.graph = graph;

    }

    public void execute() {

        List<Cell> cells = graph.getModel().getAllCells();

        for (Cell cell : cells) {

            double x = rnd.nextDouble() * 500;
            double y = rnd.nextDouble() * 500;

            cell.relocate(x, y);

        }

    }

}
```

The example looks like this:

[image]

You can drag the cells with the mouse button and zoom in and out with the mouse wheel.

---

Adding new cell types is as easy as creating subclasses of Cell:

```
package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class ButtonCell extends Cell {

    public ButtonCell(String id) {
        super(id);

        Button view = new Button(id);

        setView(view);

    }

}

package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class ImageCell extends Cell {

    public ImageCell(String id) {
        super(id);

        ImageView view = new ImageView("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");
        view.setFitWidth(100);
        view.setFitHeight(80);

        setView(view);

    }

}


package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class LabelCell extends Cell {

    public LabelCell(String id) {
        super(id);

        Label view = new Label(id);

        setView(view);

    }

}

package com.fxgraph.cells;

import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;

import com.fxgraph.graph.Cell;

public class TitledPaneCell extends Cell {

    public TitledPaneCell(String id) {
        super(id);

        TitledPane view = new TitledPane();
        view.setPrefSize(100, 80);

        setView(view);

    }

}
```

and creating the types

```
package com.fxgraph.graph;

public enum CellType {

    RECTANGLE,
    TRIANGLE,
    LABEL,
    IMAGE,
    BUTTON,
    TITLEDPANE
    ;

}
```

and creating instances depending on the type:

```
...
public void addCell(String id, CellType type) {

    switch (type) {

    case RECTANGLE:
        RectangleCell rectangleCell = new RectangleCell(id);
        addCell(rectangleCell);
        break;

    case TRIANGLE:
        TriangleCell circleCell = new TriangleCell(id);
        addCell(circleCell);
        break;

    case LABEL:
        LabelCell labelCell = new LabelCell(id);
        addCell(labelCell);
        break;

    case IMAGE:
        ImageCell imageCell = new ImageCell(id);
        addCell(imageCell);
        break;

    case BUTTON:
        ButtonCell buttonCell = new ButtonCell(id);
        addCell(buttonCell);
        break;

    case TITLEDPANE:
        TitledPaneCell titledPaneCell = new TitledPaneCell(id);
        addCell(titledPaneCell);
        break;

    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported type: " + type);
    }
}
...
```

and you'll get this

[image]

Comment: Why would you add a layer selected cells, to display them on top of everything else?

Comment: For the selection rectangle and other stuff that isn't part of the graph itself. You don't want to mess around with adding the selection JavaFX Nodes in the graph itself. Layering solves that problem. With that you can also add e. g. resize indicators directly on the corners of the rectangles.

Comment: Hi @Roland nice job! I have implemented your solution and I noticed that with a lot of data(I have implemented a graph with 4 000 nodes and 88 000 edges) there is a problem, the data takes a lot of time and do not display at all. If you put: primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show(); at the end of start method there is no problem at all and the display is fast.

Comment: I've created a github repo for this and pushed it to maven central. You can find it here: https://github.com/sirolf2009/fxgraph

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I managed to use the javascript vis.js library along with JavaFX WebView.

You can check it out on github if that's useful to someone: https://github.com/arocketman/VisFX

Answer (score 1):

I would give [Prefux](https://github.com/jchildress/Prefux) a try. It is a fork of the [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) project.

The original repository starting with JavaFX porting is https://github.com/effrafax/Prefux, but the most maintained fork seems to be the one above (https://github.com/jchildress/Prefux).

Another attempt to port to JavaFX was started at https://github.com/gedeffe/Prefuse, but it is not active anymore.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `jfreechart` api for generating graph visualization

It provides, Line , Pie, bars. and it is very eary to use.

Comment: I would... But I'm not looking to use a Swing library for JavaFX.