# Javafx size of a Button after adding it to a Container

Tags: user-interface, javafx

In case a button is added dynamically into a layout, the getWidth property adds back 0; However, the preferred size is reachable instantly. I'm assuming it's because the system didn't have a chance to calculate the size of the button ( since it's just added ).

Minimum reproducible example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AgentApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Stage tagTest = new Stage();
        VBox topBox = new VBox();
        Parent tagRoot = topBox;
        Button btn = new Button("Add a Button dynamically");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            Button dBtn = new Button("How big is this?!");
            dBtn.setOnAction(event1 -> System.out.println("Width is actually: " + dBtn.getWidth())); /* (1) */
            topBox.getChildren().add(dBtn);
            System.out.println("Width:" + dBtn.getWidth()); /* (2) */
        });
        topBox.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene tagsScene = new Scene(tagRoot,400,200);
        tagTest.setScene(tagsScene);
        tagTest.show();
    }
}
```

at `(1)` the width of the button is printed out correctly, while the width at `(2)` prints out 0.0. Which is unexpected.

Calling the `layout` function on the parent of the node ( `topbox` ) yields no results; Neither inheriting and calling the protected function `layoutChildren` in a custom container.

But somewhere down the line I assume the size itself must be calculated somewhere, since the size is calculated by the time a `dBtn` is pressed. How can the size calculation be forced at that point?

**UPDATE:**

Asking for the width asynchronously returns the correct size:

```java
Button dBtn = new Button("How big is this?!");
dBtn.setOnAction(event1 -> System.out.println("Width is actually: " + dBtn.getWidth()));
topBox.getChildren().add(dBtn);
Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println("btn width: " + btn.getWidth()));
```

But since that's an asynchronous call to be run in an unspecified time, the size is still not available instantly.

Comment: don't quite understand what you are after: actual size is only available after showing (as you probably see when doing the printout after show)

Comment: in situations when the user interface is not static, but generated dynamically:  the size of a newly added button is required for some UI related calculations.

Comment: What happens if you move your print statement after `tagTest.show();`

Comment: It prints the size correctly, but that doesn't work if the button is added by another button ( for example ) dynamically, after `show();` has been called.

Comment: sounds like your example doesn't fit your description?

Comment: THank you! I updated the code to reflect on that, I hope this makes a better example.

Comment: Why do you need to know it’s size?

Comment: I can describe it, but workarounds won't answer the question... I'd like to know because I am implementing something like the tags field in SO, by typing into a textfield and adding buttons into a flowPane in front of it. After a tag is recognized, I'd like to extend the text with spaces depending on the size of the button in front of it ( which contains other stuff too, like icons ).

Comment: What do you mean by "extend the text with spaces?" This sounds like you're looking to do more manual layout than you should need to. Perhaps providing a [mcve] would make your goal and issue more apparent.

Comment: The size is usually assigned to a node when its parent's `layoutChildren()` method is called. So the surefire way to get the correct size would be to subclass the pane, override `layoutChildren()`, call `super.layoutChildren()`, and then query the size of the node. Generally the `layoutChildren()` method is the place where layout calculations should be performed. For almost all use cases, you can use existing layout panes to manage the layout, instead of defining your own.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your input! I did what you suggested and implemented a custom VBox in which `layoutChildren` is public instead of protected, but it still has no effect on the size at the moment of adding it into the scene.

Comment: @Zephyr Thank you for the input but I'd rather not complicate the question with a usecase irrelevant to the question, which is about library behavior. I updated the example  and added some details to the question, do you think it is acceptable now?

Comment: as you noted, sizing/locating is only available _after_ the next layout pulse. Don't quite get why you would need it earlier? Why would you need to know the size when inserting a button during/after typing? That should be done by the layout automatically. Anyway, the example doesn't demonstrate your problem, just expected behaviour :)

Comment: are you saying there is no way to force size calculation other than waiting for the next layout pulse? I would also accept this as an answer, if that is the intended behavior ( or rather missing functionality ) in Javafx; and would base design decisions on this fact. Frankly I agree that the need of this specific functionality implies a fault with the design of the program.

Comment: There's no way to force a size calculation, because the ultimate size of the button depends on the amount of space available to it, which depends on, among other things, the size of its parent and sibling nodes. So it's not possible to know its size without a layout pass happening.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I supposed. Do you think there is any way to force that layout pass?

Answer (score -2):

you have to add the Node into the Scene before calling the getWif