# create generic graph avoid instanceof

Tags: java, generics, graph

Hello everybody,

I was looking for javafx implementation of graphs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679025/graph-visualisation-like-yfiles-in-javafx),
but for the id, I would like to have any type.
The problem is that when I want to show it, It depends of the type, so I can do this :

```
public class LabelCell<T> extends Cell<T> {

public LabelCell(T id) {
    super(id);
    Pane pane=new Pane();
    Label view;

    if (id instanceof SQLTableVertex) {

     String labelString="";

     labelString+=((SQLTableVertex) id).getName();
     labelString+="\n"+"________________________";
     for (Identifier i:((SQLTableVertex) id).getIdentifiers())
         labelString+= "\n" +i;

     view = new Label(labelString);

    }       

    else 
        view=new Label(id.toString());


    view.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray;");
    pane.getChildren().add(view);
    setView(pane);

}
```

But I lose the fact that it's generic.
I could also add a case in the switch of the model but it is the same problem

How can I deal with it ? Thank's by advance.

Comment: Could you make a subclass, for example `SQLTableLabelCell extends LabelCell<SQLTableVertex>` to handle the special logic for `SQLTableVertex`? The drawback is you are giving the client the responsibility for not using the general class in this case. This in turn could be encapsulated in a factory, but I believe the factory would need to use `instanceof`, so I guess you wouldn’t be quite happy;

Comment: Thank you,I can do that but I have to add a case to the switch in the model in this case, is it better than an instanceof ? Finally I've proceeded differently, I create a graph of "String" which is a string representation of SQLTableVertex and so I have no tests to do in cells.

Comment: The last sounds to me like a fairly good solution. Not knowing your full design, I cannot really tell for sure, though. There may be pros and cons, and you can best weigh them yourself.