# Resizing graph elements (gridpanes) in anchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

My task is creating the resizable graph in full screen mode. Graph must be resizable when user change the window of program that is fullscreen by default (the components and lines of graph change their sizes). I realize the graph with `AnchorPane`: the elements (that are `GridPane`s) stay in coordinates that are defined. Then I make the lines with the help of method `getBoundsInParent()`. Here is the scema of graph:

[image]

All is good but the problem is that I can t resize my graph. All components are stayed with their sizes; variables `prefSize`, `minSize`, `maxSize` don't do the resizing. I try using the params `AnchorPane.setTopAnchor` etc., but they don t resize, only move the `GridPane` component.
Also I try to use `GridPane` as the layout instead the `AnchorPane`. But my lines that are binded with the methods `component.getBoundsInParent()` fly away in random positions (I understand that the `getBoundsInParent()` method returns other coordinates that with `GridPane`).

My project is located at work computers without Internet & I can t show it. I think the way of binding the lines between graphs is useful to show in code block because it is the cause of moving out the lines when the components are in GridPane layout:

```
line.startXProperty().bind(source.layoutXProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));    
line.startYProperty().bind(source.layoutYProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
line.endXProperty().bind(target.layoutXProperty().add(target.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
line.endYProperty().bind(target.layoutYProperty().add(target.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
```

What is the way to resize the graph with elements that I create and lines that are connected with this elements. May be it s the properties of `AnchorPane` or `GridPane`? Or some binding of start & endpoints of lines?

Comment: I strongly suspect you should not be using AnchorPane at all.  It appears you are trying to manually perform the work of a layout.  Can you edit your question and show us what you are trying to achieve visually?  Either take a screen shot, or draw it in a simple paint program, or use ASCII art.

Comment: @VGR thanks for attention for my question. I have added the scema of my graph at the top of my question. As I wrote, by the default it is fullscreen but during runtime the user can change the screen size...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows the nodes you illustrate, and describe the desired result. Possible duplicate of [*Graph Visualisation (like yFiles) in JavaFX*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30679025/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings need to be based on properties or other ObservableValue implementations, so changes to their values are properly tracked.  Direct method calls like `source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0` are only evaluated once, the moment that code creates the binding, so changes to the width are never seen.

```
line.startXProperty().bind(
    source.layoutXProperty().add(
        source.widthProperty().divide(2)));
line.startYProperty().bind(
    source.layoutYProperty().add(
        source.heightProperty().divide(2)));
```

If `source` and `target` are not Regions and thus don’t have a `width` property, you can use [Bindings](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) to create a dynamic binding of their bounds:

```
DoubleBinding width = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> source.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), 
    source.layoutBoundsProperty());

line.startXProperty().bind(
    source.layoutXProperty().add(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(width.divide(2)));

DoubleBinding height = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> source.getLayoutBounds().getHeight(), 
    source.layoutBoundsProperty());

line.startYProperty().bind(
    source.layoutYProperty().add(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(height.divide(2)));
```