# JavaFX: What is the equivalent of getLowerBound for CategoryAxis

Tags: java, javafx, zooming, bar-chart

I want to zoom into a BarChart in JavaFX. I found [this project](https://github.com/gillius/jfxutils) that does that this way:

```
private final ValueAxis<?> xAxis;
private final ValueAxis<?> yAxis;

lastY = event.getY();
yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
yAxis.setLowerBound(yAxis.getLowerBound() + dY);
yAxis.setUpperBound(yAxis.getUpperBound() + dY);
```

However, I am using `CategoryAxis` for xAxis and not a `ValueAxis`. So the `getLowerBound` function doesn't exist.

How can I adapt that to be able to zoom into a BarChart using a `CategoryAxis` as an xAxis?

Comment: No time to test, but does `xAxis.getCategories().setAll(someSubsetOfCategories);` work (where `someSubsetOfCategories` is a list containing only some of the categories)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling-> You may be able to try this approach.