# JavaFX pan-able zoom-able canvas

Tags: javafx, canvas, zooming

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm having trouble creating a pan-able zoom-able canvas.

What I want to create is a Canvas within some Pane (with the area within that Pane visible) that can be panned around to some set limit and that can be zoom-able to some minimum (preferably to parent Pane's size) and maximum.

Does anyone have any archetype I can follow or is there some guide online that can help me get started with this because I'm having trouble finding any.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Start by wrapping the canvas in a group, and changing the scale of the canvas on appropriate mouse events. Then put the group in a pannable scroll pane to implement the scrolling. The question is not really focused enough for this forum.

Comment: [Related question on panning and zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling/16682180#16682180).